# Remove a key with FluentD

Tags: json, filter, fluentd

I have a JSON file, which is generated by a tool. I want to remove one attribute before I forward it.

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/app/file.json
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/file.pos # pos record
  tag file_json
  format json
</source>

<match file_json>
  @type exec
  tag_key file_filtered
  buffer_path /tmp/file_buffer.buf
  command jq 'del(.timestamp)'
  format json
</match>

<match file_filtered>
  @type file
  path /var/log/app/file_fwd.json
  # time_slice_format %Y%m%d
  # time_slice_wait 10m
  # time_format %Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z
  # compress gzip
  # utc
</match>
```

I don't know all the JSON attributes, but I know that I cannot have the `timestamp` field. I use `jq` to remove this attribute mimicking the function:

```
tail file.json | jq 'del(.timestamp)'
```

Can FluentD do this for me? The way I describe it here does not result into a filtered file, but the config gets accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See record_transformer fileter in official document.

http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/filter_record_transformer#removekeys-optional-string-type

Comment: sorry, I cannot get this to work... I somehow have the feeling that it's for TSV and not for JSON.